# ElGamal signature scheme problem and unsure whether my calculations are wrong or that's the answer

Tags: encryption, signature, elgamal-encryption, verifiability, elgamal-signature

Trying to solve problem with verifying a message through the ElGamal signature scheme and I end up getting two different values.

I'm given a prime number p=881
, e1=3,
d=60
, and a random value r=11
. I have to

a) Find e2
and the signature of the message M=300
.

b) Verify the signature.

I'm stuck on part b verifying V1 and V2
I get two different answers and I'm unsure whether I'm doing the calculations wrong or if that's the answer.

I solved e2 = 3^60 mod 881 = 490,
S1 = 3^11 mod 881 = 66,
S2 = (300 - 60*66)11^-1 mod 880 = 740 mod 880 = 740,

V1 = 3^300 mod 881 = 102
V2 = (490^66)(66^740) mod 881 = 494,
therefore, the signature is not verified

Is this the correct answer? There's a lot of calculations going on and I'd just like to know.

[Here's the diagram showing the formulas for each calculation along the ElGamal signature process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfmWK.png)

Comment: V1 and V2 should be equal. Make sure you compute [_modular_ inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), with the appropriate modulus. Are you sure you are allowed to post homework? If so, and you are still stuck, [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/108780/edit) the question to detail all your calculations. Likely, you'll find your error meanwhile.

Comment: More precise hint than the one above: In ElGamal signature, calculations of $S_1$ and $V_2$ are modulo $p$, and (thus) calculation of $S_2$ is modulo $p-1$. It follows the choice of $r$ is incorrect w.r.t. $p$, because it leaves $r^{-1}$ undefined, thus $S_2$ undefined and the proposed value for $S_2$ invalid. The requirement on $r$ is stated in red in the figure (with a typo: read "relatively prime to" or "coprime with" where there is "relative prime to"). I recommend that you make an answer to your own question.